# GDM Can't unlock screen

Tags: gnome, manjaro, gdm

Recently I've upgraded GNOME (GDM etc.) from 3.28 to 3.30 on my Manjaro. I have ASUS GL552VW notebook running linux 4.14 and intel-i915 driver, nouveau is blacklisted and nvidia is not installed. Before update I could lock screen and unlock by pressing any key and entering my password. When I lock my GNOME screen now, it locks but I cannot unlock, touchpad works, keyboard backlight works, display is on, slide animation (three arrows on bottom edge of screen) of GNOME curtain works, but the curtain doesn't slide on key press and I can't enter password. The temporary solution I've made is using legacy gnome-screensaver and LightDM instead GDM but it isn't good solution... What can I do to make GDM working as it should?

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled xorg-xprop and this problem gone away.

Comment: After I installed Deepin this problem gone away too... Sad to say that (GNOME was the best for me), but everyone wants to use computer not to fight with computer.